# Are Hyperbolic Angles Smaller than Euclidean ones in 'Congruent' Triangles?

Tags: trigonometry, metric-geometry

Assume you have a triangle with vertices $A,B,C\in\mathbb H^2$ in the hyperbolic plane and the hyperbolic distances are $a=d(B,C), b=d(A,C), c=d(A,B)$.

Now pick a `comparison triangle' $A',B',C'\in\mathbb R^2$ with the same side-lengths $a,b,c$ as our hyperbolic triangle.

Is it true that each angle $\alpha=\angle_{CAB},\beta=\angle_{ABC},\gamma=\angle_{BCA}$ in the hyperbolic triangle is bounded above by the corresponding angle in the Euclidean triangle, i.e. $\alpha\leq\alpha',\beta\leq\beta',\gamma\leq\gamma'$?

I tried the approach of comparing the cosines of the angles via the respective laws of cosines:
$$\cos\alpha'=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\overset?\leq\frac{\cosh a\cosh b-\cosh c}{\sinh a\sinh b}=\cos\alpha,$$
however, I was not able to prove this inequality yet.

Comment: This is called "angle comparison theorem", usually proven using Rauch's theorem on Jacobi fields.

Comment: Thank you very much @MoisheKohan! I have now started looking into this topic a bit, and it indeed seems to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

At  least one of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$  is smaller because $\alpha+ \beta+ \gamma < \pi .$  Then we use
$$  \frac{ \sin \alpha}{\sinh a} =  \frac{ \sin \beta}{\sinh b} =  \frac{ \sin \gamma}{\sinh c} $$  and the fact that $\sinh x > x$ for $x > 0$

Comment: I don't quite see why that follows from the law of sines, but obviously $\alpha+\beta+\gamma<\pi$ while $\alpha'+\beta'+\gamma'=\pi$, so I agree that one of them has to be larger.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Unfortunately, that is not enough for my case. I really need that one specific, predetermined angle is smaller than or equal.